# Use purescript-halogen (with pulp)

Tags: purescript, halogen

Following [PureScript by Example](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read), I'm using [pulp](https://github.com/bodil/pulp) for installing packages.

[Halogen](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-halogen#introduction) requires `virtual-dom` as extra dependency. From the documentation and the example packages, it seems to me that adding it involves a bunch of build tools that I haven't used before (`gulp`, `webpack`, `bower`, etc.). I downloaded the examples and tried to run them  with `npm install & npm run example` but I got `unknwon module` errors.

So, I'd like to know a minimal viable way to install halogen into a new `pulp` project (which hopefully doesn't require me to delve into the slew of build tools, or at least not for small projects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to build it with `pulp browserify --to some-file.js` - the Browserify option is there for situations like this, where you want to produce a single JS file from a collection of CommonJS modules that may include `npm` dependencies.

Comment: What's the sequence of steps, after `pulp init`, which results in me being able to run (`pulp run`) my program that imports halogen?

Comment: I don't think you ever want to `pulp run` this - it's for running things in `node` directly - not so useful for a front-end web app! `pulp server` might be more useful however, as that will watch your source files and run a local development server on http://localhost:1337/. It'll incorporate the `virtual-dom` dependency also.

Comment: Thanks, I did `browserify` and included the output in a html file, and it worked. Could you also tell me how to use `pulp build`? I tried it the same way, but it couldn't find `require` at first, then after I included `require.js` it couldn't load `virtual-dom`.

Comment: How can I use `pulp server`? It just displays a directory tree for me on localhost, or views `index.html` in the project directory, but doesn't reload or recompile anything if I change my sources.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see these until now, glad you got it figured out! The [PureScript IRC channel](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=purescript) may be able to help you out in a timely fashion if you run into problems like this again.